# Selenium getting stuck on data:, (MS Edge)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use Selenium to navigate to a website. Selenium opens up the browser but does not navigate further to the specified website URL, but gets stuck on the "data:," url. After some time time I get the following exception:

*"The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:58504/session timed out after 60 seconds"*

Note: I did not specify the 58504 port anymore, so I guess it is the default port that Selenium use?

I am programming in C# and using the following Nuget Packages:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/4.1.1
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebDriverManager/2.13.0

Here is the code:

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
    using WebDriverManager;
    using WebDriverManager.DriverConfigs.Impl;
    using WebDriverManager.Helpers;
    
    public void VisitWebsite() 
    {
        IWebDriver driver = null;

        try  
        {
            new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new EdgeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser);
    
            EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox);
            options.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
            options.AddArgument("--dns-prefetch-disable");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-software-rastersizer");
    
            driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {   
            throw ex;
        }
    
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
    }
```

Where does it go wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I same the problem, do you have any solution?

Comment: Hi @BìnhNguyễnQuang. My issue was that the DeveloperToolsAvailability policy was set to a value that "blocks" Selenium. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp#developer-tools-availability-policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It seems the DeveloperToolsAvailability policy for the MSEdge browser had a value that "blocks" Selenium from working. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp#developer-tools-availability-policy